# Block custom fields after a single registration?

Tags: custom-fields, activities, admin

We currently have a set of **custom fields** specifically for CiviCRM **activities**. We would like to enable the **record lock feature** after registering a single occasion so that the user cannot modify or delete them. Is it possible to make it combinable?

[image]

These custom fields are combinable and will be added historically in an activity and should not be modified or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension called 'Activity Type ACL' that should do what you want.  You could give users 'add' and 'view' permission for an activity type, but not 'edit' or 'delete'. But that would restrict access to the whole activity, not just he custom fields. More on this extension here https://civicrm.org/extensions/activity-type-acl